# ReactNative i can't pass to another page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to do the login page with signInWithEmailAndPassword function of firebase.auth()
I can create the user, but i can't do the login and i don't understand why.

When i click the button (touchableOpacity) i should go to the signIn function that do the login and pass to another page. But instead, it doesn't do anything, no error but neither the navigation or the error for the wrong email.

The navigation is correctly implemented even because the function to create the user works and i navigate to the same page.

Here my functions:

**EDIT: This is my full code of Login Page**

```
import getIdByEmail from './firebase/getIdByEmail';
import {IdContext} from './Context';


async function pushClient(email) {
  //I WANT TO PASS SIZE+1 TO ALL PAGES
  const size = await getID('Clients');
  const newID = (size + 1).toString();
  const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').doc(newID);
  await docRef.set({
    Email: email
  });
  return (size+1);
}

async function getID(){ 
  const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').get();
  return snapshot.size;
}

export default const LoginApp = props => {
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [Pass, setPass] = useState();
    const [SignPress, setSignPress] = useState();
    const [CreatePress, setCreatePress] = useState();
    const [id, setId] = useContext(IdContext);

    const signIn = async(props) => {
        const ID = await getIdByEmail(Email);
          firebase.auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Pass)
          .then(() => {
              setId(ID);
              props.navigation.navigate('Skip'); 
          })
          .catch(error => {
              if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
              console.log('That email address is already in use!');
              }
  
              if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
              console.log('That email address is invalid!');
              }
              console.error(error);
          });
    }

    const createUser = () => {
        firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Pass)
        .then(() => {
            pushClient(Email).then(id => {
              setId(id);
              props.navigation.navigate('ChooseRole');
            }); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
            console.log('That email address is already in use!');
            }

            if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
            console.log('That email address is invalid!');
            }

            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    return(
      <View>
          <Button title="Create User" onPress={() => setCreatePress(!CreatePress)}/>
            {CreatePress &&
              <View >
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                  onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                  onChangeText={text => setPass(text)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={createUser} style={styles.loginBtn}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View> 
            }
          <Button title="Sign In with Email" onPress={() => setSignPress(!SignPress)}/>
            {SignPress &&
              <View>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                  onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputText}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                  onChangeText={text => setPass(text)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={signIn} style={styles.loginBtn}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View> 
            }
          <Text> Welcome</Text>
      </View>
  );
}
```

**getIdByEmail.js**

```
const getIdByEmail = email => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('Clients').get().then(data => {
            data.docs.map(doc => {
                const d = doc.data();
                if (d.email === email) resolve(doc.id);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT: I want that when the user click the button signIn, the inputText appear for insert Email and Password, then they click on "Continue" and the system should calculate the ID of the document (that I ASSIGNED when they create the account) in which there is their email; After that, i want to pass to another page called "Skip" (same navigator)

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's different?  We can't see any of the variables or document data here, so we don't really know what will happen with getIdByEmail.  Please edit the question to include enough data so that anyone can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I edit it, let me know if now is better

Answer (score 1):

my best guess is the email may not exists in the docs, and your promise never resolve nor reject, so ID await forever, firebase.auth() never run. Try reject it if no email can be matched.

```
//..getIdByEmail.js
const getIdByEmail = email => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('Clients').get().then(data => {
            data.docs.map(doc => {
                const d = doc.data();
                if (d.email === email) resolve(doc.id);
            });
            reject("no email");
        });
    });
}



//..Login Page 
const signIn = async(props) => {
        const ID = await getIdByEmail(Email).catch(err=>{
             if(err=="no email"){
               console.log("no email")
             }else{
               console.err(e);
             }
        })
```

//....
}